# What is the difference between current and available pod replicas in kubernetes deployment?

Tags: deployment, kubernetes, kubernetes-deployment, kubernetes-cluster

I am trying to get my hands dirty on Kubernetes. I am firing following command:

```
kubectl get deployment
```

and I get the following headers in the output:

[image: kubectll get deployment]

I can't find the difference between `current` and `available` columns in the following output?

I know that official documentation gives a small description each of these fields, but it doesn't answer my following questions:

1. Is `Current` <= `Desired` true?
2. Is `Up-to-Date` <= `Current` true?
3. Is `Up-to-Date` > `Current` and `Up-to-Date` <= `Desired` true?
4. Is `Available` always <= `Current` OR it can be > `Available`?

In short, what is the relation between all these fields?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Deployment object specifies the desired state of your Deployment, and the Deployment Controller drives the current state of the system towards the desired state.

The `Desired` field specifies the number of replicas you asked for, while the `Current` field specifies the number of replicas that are currently running in the system. The `Up-To-Date` field indicates the number of replicas that are up to date with the desired state. The `Available` field shows the number of replicas that are passing readiness probes (if defined).

1. Is `Current` always <= `Desired`? No, current can be greater than desired during a deployment update.
2. Is `Up-to-date` always <= `Current`? I believe the answer here is yes.
3. Is `Up-to-date` > `Current`? No, up-to-date should be the same as current, or less than current during a deployment update.
4. Is `Available` always <= `Current`? Yes.

I encourage you to go through a deployment update and scale out/in while using `watch` to monitor these fields as the controller converges current state to desired state.