# What is 'AVAILABLE' column in kubernetes daemonsets

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, daemonset

I may have a stupid question but could someone explain what "Available" correctly represent in DaemonSets? I checked [What is the difference between current and available pod replicas in kubernetes deployment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51085740/what-is-the-difference-between-current-and-available-pod-replicas-in-kubernetes) answer but there are no readiness errors.

In cluster i see below status:

```
$ kubectl get ds -n kube-system
NAME           DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR                
kube-proxy     6         6         5       6            5           beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux
```

Why it is showing as 5 instead of 6?

all pods are running perfectly fine without any "readiness" errors or restarts?

```
$ kubectl get pods -n kube-system | grep kube-proxy
kube-proxy-cv7vv                       1/1     Running   0          20d
kube-proxy-kcd67                       1/1     Running   0          20d
kube-proxy-l4nfk                       1/1     Running   0          20d
kube-proxy-mkvjd                       1/1     Running   0          87d
kube-proxy-qb7nz                       1/1     Running   0          36d
kube-proxy-x8l87                       1/1     Running   0          87d
```

Could someone tell what can be checked further?

Comment: can you add output of `kubectl describe ds kube-proxy -n kube-system` to see logs and additional info?

Answer (score 0):

The `Available` field shows the number of replicas or pods that are ready to accept traffic and passed all the criterion such as readiness or liveness probe or any other condition that verifies that your application is ready to serve the requests coming from user.